# Is there a way to automate the extraction of the Microsoft Office 365 Quarantine Data CSV file into Multiple CSV Files?

Tags: r, csv

When I ran a security report through the Office 365 Admin Email Explorer to obtain detailed information about emails and their respective types of attacks, I downloaded the .csv file and manually use Microsoft Excel to filter out exact email subject rows and save to their own .csv file. This took a long time to create individual CSV files since there were quite a lot of various emails with same or differing subject titles as values.

1. Downloaded the .csv fild from the Office 365 Admin portal with a date range of 7 days into the past (date-range).
2. Imported into R using the R command below:

`Office_365_Report_CSV = "C:/Users/absnd/Documents/2022-11-18office365latestquarantine.csv"`

3. Imported the table from the library.

`require(data.table)`

4. Created a new variable to convert the data into a data-frame.

`quarantine_data = fread(paste0(Office_365_Report_CSV),sep = ",", header = TRUE, check. Names = FALSE)`

5. Pull columns needed to filter through in the data-frame.

`Quarantine_Columns = quarantine_data[,c("Email date (UTC)","Recipients","Subject","Sender","Sender IP","Sender domain","Delivery action","Latest delivery location","Original delivery location","Internet message ID","Network message ID","Mail language","Original recipients","Additional actions","Threats","File threats","File hash","Detection technologies","Alert ID","Final system override","Tenant system override(s)","User system override(s)","Directionality","URLs","Sender tags","Recipient tags","Exchange transport rule","Connector","Context" )]`

6. Steps Needed to be done (I am not sure where to go from here):
   -I would like to have R write to individual .csv file with the same "Subject" value rows that must contain all the above columns data in step 5.

> Sub-step - ex. If the row data contains the value inside the column (named, "Threats") = "Phish" generate a file named, "YYYY-MM-DD Phishing <number increment +1>.csv."

> Sub-step - ex. 2 If the row data contains the value inside the column (named, "Threats") = Phish, Spam" generate a CSV file named, "YYYY-MM-DD Phishing and Spam <number increment +1>.csv."

Step 6 and so on would filter out like same "Subject" column values for rows and save the rows with same Subject email values into a single file that would be named based on the if-condition in the substeps above in step 6.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are looking to do this in R - RStudio is an IDE to make usage of R easier.

If you save your data frames in a list, and then set a vector of the names of the files that you want to give each of those files, you can then use `purrr::walk2()` to iterate through the saving. Some reproducible code as an example:

```
library(purrr)
library(glue)
library(readr)

mydfs_l <- list(mtcars, iris)

file_names <- c("mtcars_file", "iris_file")

walk2(mydfs_l, file_names, function(x, y) {  write_excel_csv(x, glue("mypath/to/files/{y}.csv")) })
```

Comment: split_subjects = split(Phishing_Data_Results, Phishing_Data_Results$Subject)

walk2(split_subjects, "2022-11-21 Phish", function(x, y) {  write_excel_csv(x, glue("C:/Users/absnd/Downloads/{y}.csv")) })


But I only get one file that contained 1 of a kind of the email subject. I want the system to check for the next unique email column row and create a new file and etc for the .csv files to spit out. Let me know.

Comment: Yes, because your second argument in `walk2()` needs to be of the same length as the list given in your first argument. Here you only gave it a vector of length 1 ("2022-11-21 Phish")

Comment: In the code I have given above, I'm using an example in which both objects `mydfs_l` and `file_names` are of the same length (2).